# Error plotting a time column as x-axis ticks

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a `df` as follows

```
    Time    Samstag
0   00:15:00    80.6
1   00:30:00    74.6
2   00:45:00    69.2
3   01:00:00    63.6
4   01:15:00    57.1
5   01:30:00    50.4
6   01:45:00    44.1
7   02:00:00    39.1
8   02:15:00    36.0
9   02:30:00    34.4
10  02:45:00    33.7
11  03:00:00    33.3
12  03:15:00    32.7
13  03:30:00    32.0
14  03:45:00    31.5
15  04:00:00    31.3
16  04:15:00    31.5
17  04:30:00    31.7
18  04:45:00    31.5
19  05:00:00    30.3
20  05:15:00    28.1
21  05:30:00    26.4
22  05:45:00    27.1
23  06:00:00    32.3
24  06:15:00    42.9
25  06:30:00    56.2
26  06:45:00    68.5
27  07:00:00    76.3
28  07:15:00    77.0
29  07:30:00    72.9
30  07:45:00    67.3
31  08:00:00    63.6
32  08:15:00    64.5
33  08:30:00    69.5
34  08:45:00    77.4
35  09:00:00    87.1
36  09:15:00    97.4
37  09:30:00    108.4
38  09:45:00    119.9
39  10:00:00    132.1
40  10:15:00    144.7
41  10:30:00    156.7
42  10:45:00    166.9
43  11:00:00    174.1
44  11:15:00    177.4
45  11:30:00    177.7
46  11:45:00    176.2
47  12:00:00    174.1
48  12:15:00    172.6
49  12:30:00    172.0
50  12:45:00    172.4
51  13:00:00    174.1
52  13:15:00    177.1
53  13:30:00    180.4
54  13:45:00    183.0
55  14:00:00    183.9
56  14:15:00    182.4
57  14:30:00    179.5
58  14:45:00    176.6
59  15:00:00    175.1
60  15:15:00    176.0
61  15:30:00    178.9
62  15:45:00    182.8
63  16:00:00    186.8
64  16:15:00    190.3
65  16:30:00    193.8
66  16:45:00    197.9
67  17:00:00    203.5
68  17:15:00    210.8
69  17:30:00    218.8
70  17:45:00    226.3
71  18:00:00    231.8
72  18:15:00    234.4
73  18:30:00    234.5
74  18:45:00    233.0
75  19:00:00    230.9
76  19:15:00    228.7
77  19:30:00    226.9
78  19:45:00    225.3
79  20:00:00    224.0
80  20:15:00    223.0
81  20:30:00    221.5
82  20:45:00    218.9
83  21:00:00    214.2
84  21:15:00    207.0
85  21:30:00    197.0
86  21:45:00    184.4
87  22:00:00    169.2
88  22:15:00    151.8
89  22:30:00    133.7
90  22:45:00    116.7
91  23:00:00    102.7
92  23:15:00    93.0
93  23:30:00    86.6
94  23:45:00    82.2
```

I am trying to plot this as follows:

```
sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Samstag", data=w_df)
plt.xticks(rotation=15)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("KWH")
plt.show()
```

and it gives:

[image]

The label of x-axis is `00:00, 05:33:20, ....` and so on.

I am trying to plot the `Time` column as the ticks in x-axis

I tried:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(w_df["Time"], format='%H:%M:%S')
t = t.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Samstag", data=w_df)
plt.xticks(ticks=t, rotation=15)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("KWH")
plt.show()
```

It  throws the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 2, in 
>       plt.xticks(ticks=t, rotation=15)
>
> File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py",
>   line 1540, in xticks
>       locs = ax.set_xticks(ticks)
>
> File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
>   line 3350, in set_xticks
>       ret = self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
>
> File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py",
>   line 1755, in set_ticks
>       self.set_view_interval(min(ticks), max(ticks))
>
> File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py",
>   line 1892, in setter
>       setter(self, min(vmin, vmax, oldmin), max(vmin, vmax, oldmax),
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and
>   'str'

Can anyone please tell the mistake that I am doing?

Also,

```
w_df.dtypes
Out[27]: 
Time        object
Samstag    float64
Sonntag    float64
Werktag    float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took some of your data and attempted to get your result. Unfortunately, my Seaborn plot is plotting in the same format that you would like. This may have to do with the format of your time column. When I made my small dataset from your example, I made the time column a string, and it appears that everything is plotting fine.

```
d = {'Time': ["00:15:00", "00:30:00", "00:45:00", "01:00:00", "01:15:00", "01:30:00", "01:45:00", 
"02:00:00", "02:15:00", "02:30:00", "02:45:00", "03:00:00", "03:15:00", "03:30:00", "03:45:00", 
"04:00:00", "04:15:00", "04:30:00", "04:45:00", "05:00:00", "05:15:00", "05:30:00", 
"05:45:00", "06:00:00"],
'Samstag': [80.6, 74.6,69.2, 62.6, 57.1,50.4, 44.1, 39.1, 36.0, 34.4, 33.7,33.3, 32.7, 32.0, 
31.5, 31.3, 31.5, 31.7, 31.5,30.3, 28.1, 26.4, 27.1, 32.3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

sns.lineplot(x="Time", y="Samstag", data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=15)
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("KWH")
plt.show()
```

This makes every time stamp a tick mark. Perhaps you can change your time column to be a string, if it is not already.

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(str)
```